# Is there a "share this" for Facebook which isn't a pop-up?

Tags: facebook, popup, share

I want to add "share this on Facebook" to a page. I've got this working just fine using this URL format:

http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=my.url.here

but the problem is, that's designed specifically to be a popup window, so

- the page looks weird at full browser size
- the buttons are a long way from the fields
- after submission, the page has messages in it like "this window will close shortly"

So, is there a Facebook URL which can do the same thing, but which isn't intended as a popup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Facebook Connect

http://developers.facebook.com/connect.php

It is there new JS API...

The method you want to call when you get everything lined up is:

FB.Connect.showFeedDialog(bundle_id, post_data, null, null, FB.FeedStorySize.full, FB.RequireConnect.promptConnect, function (w) {alert('shared');});

Answer (score 0):

facebook connect javascript SDK has been changed..
its here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Thanks